# Calculate a log of two columns into total amount

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a log of points that I want to import somewhere else as (email - total points).

I'm trying to figure out a query that does the following:

1. Calculate points for EACH user_id, and merging those user_ids so they won't be duplicated.
2. After that, I need to replace the USER_IDs with corresponding emails in another table:

Source Table

```
USER_ID        Points
-------        ------

1                10
2                30
3                50
1                -5
2                 5
3                -40
```

Desired result

```
USER_ID        Points
-------        ------

1                5
2                35
3                10
```

**STEP 2**

Another Source Table

```
USER_ID        Email
-------        ------

1                one@one.com
2                two@two.com
3                three@three.com
```

Final Desired result:

```
USER_ID                Total Points
-------                -----------

one@one.com              5
two@two.com              35
three@three.com          10
```

Comment: Pretty simple `join` with `group by` and `sum`.  What have you tried?

Comment: tried `inner join` but I think I got the syntax wrong :(

Comment: Try showing us perhaps?  Very basic example here: `select field, sum(anotherfield) from t1 join t2 on t1.field = t2.field group by field`

Comment: @Updula Show us your syntax, and we'll tell you what you did wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: @Barmar prev try was based on another answer, I honestly don't know.

Comment: Obviously you don't know the correct syntax, but we're not going to do it for you from scratch. You have to show your attempt, then we show how to fix it.

Comment: @sgeddes whoa this seems to be working `select oc_customer.email, sum(oc_customer_reward.points) from oc_customer_reward join oc_customer on oc_customer_reward.customer_id = oc_customer.customer_id group by oc_customer.customer_id` does it seem right?

Comment: @Updula That's exactly right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pretify your query you can write like that :

```
select oc_customer.email,
sum(oc_customer_reward.points) as Total_points
from oc_customer_reward
inner join oc_customer using(customer_id)
group by customer_id
```